# Adding elements to the front of a queue without using STL

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, queue

I am trying to add some elements to the front of an queue that already has other items.My code works fine but it adds the item in front everytime. How can I modify it to add the next item after the front added one. This is what i got:

```
void Queue::addtoFront(string first, string last){
 Node *temp = new Node(first, last, NULL);
    temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
}
```

Comment: You want it to consistently add an element at the back of the queue(near the NULL pointer) or at the second element (the one after the front)?

Comment: Sounds like you want an `addQueueToFront` function. Build a second queue with the ordering you desire, then and add the whole queue all at once.

Comment: After adding item to the front, the next item I add using this function should go after the other front one

Comment: That would violate the contract implied by a name like `addtoFront`. I recommend a different name if you really do wish this behaviour.

Comment: These are some particular items that i want to add to the front, but it should be first in first out, how could i possibly change that? These items would go to front but after the first front added one, second one should be after

Comment: maybe you mean to use a stack?

Comment: No I am just trying to figure out how to add an item after the first added one

Comment: If you want to add items at the other end, you might need a `tail` pointer as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: I'm not sure what you are trying to achive, but you could write a 'insertAfter' member function. This function takes a new element and inserts it immediately after a given element in the linked list.

To do so you must first set up the 'next' link of the new element, then insert the new element immediately after the requested element.

```
void Queue::insert(Node *newElement, Node *insertAfter)
{
    _ASSERT(insertAfter != nullptr);
    _ASSERT(newElement != nullptr);
    // set the 'next' of the new element to the 'next' of the insertAfter
    newElement->next = insertAfter->next;
    // now insert the new element immediately after the 'insertAfter'
    insertAfter->next = newElement;
}

// Taken from the original post...
// Of course, "addToFront" is no longer the correct name for this function,
// since it does no longer add the element to the front
void Queue::addToFront(...)
{
    if (head==nullptr) {
        // see original post above
    } else {
        // insert new element at the 2nd position in the queue,
        // immediately behind the head
        insert(temp, head);
    }
}
```

For further study you could read about *linked lists* and have a look at the std::list interface. And you might want to improve your code with shared_ptr/unique_ptr instead of using *Node**. In modern C++ you would almost never use

```
Node *element=new Node();
```

This is just bad code most of the time. Managing pointers and object lifetime by yourself is an
invitation to all sorts of nasty problems (memory leaks, access violations,
shallow vs. deep copy problems, failure to free objects esp. after exceptions etc...). Using managed or smart pointers make your life a lot easier:

```
shared_ptr<Node> element(new Node());
// or even better
shared_ptr<Node> element=std::make_shared<Node>();
```

Note: "managed/smart pointers" have nothing to do with C#/C++ managed code. The name simply says that there is a class (shared_ptr) that does some kind of automatic management and takes some of the burdon of you.